# What are some fatherhood insights?

Tags: parents

I am not a father and society gets a lot of fine insight into what it means to be a mother but I'm curious about those profound realisations fathers have at any stage of raising a child.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is way too broad and open-ended.  Please refer to our [faq].  "If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you're asking too much."

Comment: Agreed. About half the questions on the site cover what it means to be a father either directly or indirectly. If you'd like a book, I found Marcus Berkmann's "Fatherhood" to fairly definitive.

Comment: I agree that this question is too vague, but let's cut it down into size. Is there anything more _specific_ that you want to ask?

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen I've deleted your comment as it is not appropriate to adult discussion. Our rules are community driven. If you'd like to participate, I suggest familiarizing yourself with the community expectations. If the concept that a community has expectations about the content offends you, then we may not be a good fit for you. Best of luck.

Comment: If your question was on-topic, I'd put effort into answering it. Since it wasn't, I acted as a moderator.  I put effort into responding to your anger-driven rant to give you a chance to adjust to our community, again, as a moderator. Clearly you have no interest in taking that opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you previously thought was important, is not.

The taste of beer is a distant memory.

You've never really experienced love until you see your own child.

Managing the first month of a new baby is the hardest thing you will ever do. Much harder than those survival courses. But this one you will survive, and it will come oh so naturally.